CKEditor5 automatically removes <a> Tags Inside <figure> element when binding HTML content to editor
I'm using @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular version ^4.0.0 in my Angular project. I have a requirement to keep the <a> tags inside <figure> tags when reloading content into the CKEditor. However, these <a> tags are removed when the content is reloaded.
Here's what I've tried so far:

I created a Custom Build. Here is Configuration



import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';    
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';
import Autoformat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat';
import AutoImage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/autoimage';
import AutoLink from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/autolink';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote';
import BlockToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/toolbar/block/blocktoolbar';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Base64UploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/base64uploadadapter';
import CloudServices from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services/src/cloudservices';
import Code from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/code';
import CodeBlock from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import FindAndReplace from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-find-and-replace/src/findandreplace';
import FontBackgroundColor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontbackgroundcolor';
import FontColor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontcolor';
import FontFamily from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontfamily';
import FontSize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontsize';
import GeneralHtmlSupport from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support/src/generalhtmlsupport';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading';
import Highlight from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-highlight/src/highlight';
import HorizontalLine from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-horizontal-line/src/horizontalline';
import HtmlComment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support/src/htmlcomment';
import HtmlEmbed from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-embed/src/htmlembed';
import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image';
import ImageCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagecaption';
import ImageInsert from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageinsert';
import ImageResize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageresize';
import ImageStyle from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagestyle';
import ImageToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagetoolbar';
import ImageUpload from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageupload';
import Indent from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent/src/indent';
import IndentBlock from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent/src/indentblock';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import Link from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import LinkImage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/linkimage';
import List from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list';
import ListProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/listproperties';
import MediaEmbed from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembed';
import Mention from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-mention/src/mention';
import PageBreak from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-page-break/src/pagebreak';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import PasteFromOffice from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office/src/pastefromoffice';
import PictureEditing from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/pictureediting';
import RemoveFormat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-remove-format/src/removeformat';
import SourceEditing from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing/src/sourceediting';
import SpecialCharacters from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacters';
import SpecialCharactersArrows from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersarrows';
import SpecialCharactersCurrency from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterscurrency';
import SpecialCharactersEssentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersessentials';
import SpecialCharactersLatin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterslatin';
import SpecialCharactersMathematical from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersmathematical';
import SpecialCharactersText from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterstext';
import StandardEditingMode from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-restricted-editing/src/standardeditingmode';
import Strikethrough from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/strikethrough';
import Style from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-style/src/style';
import Subscript from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/subscript';
import Superscript from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/superscript';
import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table';
import TableCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecaption';
import TableCellProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecellproperties';
import TableColumnResize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecolumnresize';
import TableProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tableproperties';
import TableToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar';
import TextPartLanguage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-language/src/textpartlanguage';
import TextTransformation from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing/src/texttransformation';
import TodoList from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/todolist';
import Underline from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/underline';

class ClassicEditorCustom extends ClassicEditor {
}


const plugins = [
  Alignment,
  Autoformat,
  AutoImage,
  AutoLink,
  Base64UploadAdapter,
  BlockQuote,
  BlockToolbar,
  Bold,
  CloudServices,
  Code,
  CodeBlock,
  Essentials,
  FindAndReplace,
  FontBackgroundColor,
  FontColor,
  FontFamily,
  FontSize,
  GeneralHtmlSupport,
  Heading,
  Highlight,
  HorizontalLine,
  HtmlComment,
  HtmlEmbed,
  Image,
  ImageCaption,
  ImageInsert,
  ImageResize,
  ImageStyle,
  ImageToolbar,
  ImageUpload,
  Indent,
  IndentBlock,
  Italic,
  Link,
  LinkImage,
  List,
  ListProperties,
  MediaEmbed,
  Mention,
  PageBreak,
  Paragraph,
  PasteFromOffice,
  PictureEditing,
  RemoveFormat,
  SourceEditing,
  SpecialCharacters,
  SpecialCharactersArrows,
  SpecialCharactersCurrency,
  SpecialCharactersEssentials,
  SpecialCharactersLatin,
  SpecialCharactersMathematical,
  SpecialCharactersText,
  StandardEditingMode,
  Strikethrough,
  Style,
  Subscript,
  Superscript,
  Table,
  TableCaption,
  TableCellProperties,
  TableColumnResize,
  TableProperties,
  TableToolbar,
  TextPartLanguage,
  TextTransformation,
  TodoList,
  Underline
];

// Plugins to include in the build.
ClassicEditorCustom.builtinPlugins = plugins;

// Editor configuration.
ClassicEditorCustom.defaultConfig = {
  language: 'en',
  toolbar: {
    shouldNotGroupWhenFull: false,
    items: [
      // --- Document-wide tools ----------------------------------------------------------------------
      'undo',
      'redo',
      '|',
      {
        label: 'Basic styles',
        icon: 'text',
        items: [
          'fontSize',
          'fontFamily',
          'fontColor',
          'fontBackgroundColor']
      },
      'highlight',
      '|',
      // --- Basic styles, font and inline formatting -------------------------------------------------------
      'bold',
      'italic',
      '|',
      // --- Lists and indentation --------------------------------------------------------------------
      'bulletedList',
      'numberedList',
      'todoList',
      '|',
      'alignment',
      'outdent',
      'indent',
      '|',
      'insertTable',
      'link',
      'insertImage',
      'mediaEmbed',
      '|',
      'specialCharacters',
      'removeFormat',
      '|',
      'underline',
      'strikethrough',
      'superscript',
      'subscript',
      'code',
      '|',
      'blockQuote',
      'codeBlock',
      'htmlEmbed',
      'pageBreak',
      'horizontalLine',
      '-',
      '|',
      'findAndReplace',
      'selectAll',
      '|',
      'sourceEditing',
      '|',
      // --- Block-level formatting -------------------------------------------------------------------
      'heading',
      '|',
      'style'
    ]
  },
  fontFamily: {
    supportAllValues: true
  },
  fontSize: {
    options: [10, 12, 14, 'default', 18, 20, 22],
    supportAllValues: true
  },
  heading: {
    options: [
      {model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph'},
      {model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1'},
      {model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2'},
      {model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Heading 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3'},
      {model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Heading 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4'},
      {model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Heading 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5'},
      {model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Heading 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6'}
    ]
  },
  htmlEmbed: {
    showPreviews: true
  },
  htmlSupport: {
    allow: [
      // Enables all HTML features.
      {
        name: /.*/,
        attributes: true,
        classes: true,
        styles: true
      }
    ],
    disallow: [
      {
        attributes: [
          {key: /.*/, value: /data:(?!image\/(png|jpeg|gif|webp))/i}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  image: {
    styles: ['alignCenter', 'alignLeft', 'alignRight'],
    resizeOptions: [
      {
        name: 'resizeImage:original',
        label: 'Default image width',
        value: null
      },
      {
        name: 'resizeImage:50',
        label: '50% page width',
        value: '50'
      },
      {
        name: 'resizeImage:75',
        label: '75% page width',
        value: '75'
      }
    ],
    toolbar: [
      'imageTextAlternative', 'toggleImageCaption',
      '|',
      'imageStyle:inline', 'imageStyle:wrapText', 'imageStyle:breakText', 'imageStyle:side',
      '|',
      'resizeImage'
    ],
    insert: {
      integrations: ['insertImageViaUrl']
    }
  },
  list: {
    properties: {
      styles: true,
      startIndex: true,
      reversed: true
    }
  },
  link: {
    decorators: {
      toggleDownloadable: {
        mode: 'manual',
        label: 'Downloadable',
        attributes: {
          download: 'file'
        }
      }
    },
    addTargetToExternalLinks: true,
    defaultProtocol: 'https://'
  },
  placeholder: 'Type or paste your content here!',
  table: {
    contentToolbar: [
      'tableColumn',
      'tableRow',
      'mergeTableCells',
      'tableProperties',
      'tableCellProperties',
      'toggleTableCaption'
    ]
  }
};

export default {ClassicEditorCustom};




The code in ts file



import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ClassicEditorCustom} from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ckeditor-component',
  templateUrl: './ckeditor-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ckeditor-component.component.scss']
})
export class CkeditorComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  editor: any;
  value = '<figure class="image"><a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/sliced-bread-with-vegetable-on-white-ceramic-plate-6unxGRCPg0U" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598532213919-078e54dd1f40?q=80&w=464&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D 464w"></a></figure>';

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editor = ClassicEditorCustom;
  }

  public onReady(editor: any) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        editor.ui.getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(
          editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
          editor.ui.getEditableElement()
        );
      }, 500);
  }
}




Code in html file



<ckeditor [editor]="editor"
          [(ngModel)]="value"
          (ready)="onReady($event)">
</ckeditor>



Issue:
When I reload content that contains an <a> tag inside a <figure> tag, the <a> tag is removed. Here’s an example of the content:
<figure class="image"><a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/sliced-bread-with-vegetable-on-white-ceramic-plate-6unxGRCPg0U" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598532213919-078e54dd1f40?q=80&w=464&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D 464w"></a></figure>

After reloading into the editor, it becomes:
<figure class="image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598532213919-078e54dd1f40?q=80&w=464&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D 464w"></figure>

Dependencies:

@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular: ^4.0.0
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic: ^36.0.1
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support: ^36.0.1
All dependencies use ^36.0.1

Steps to Reproduce:

Insert content with an <a> tag inside a <figure> tag into the editor.
Reload the content into the editor.

Expected Result:
The <a> tag inside the <figure> tag should be preserved after reloading the content.
Actual Result:
The <a> tag is removed, and only the image inside the <a> tag remains.
Question:
How can I ensure that the <a> tags inside <figure> tags are preserved when reloading content into CKEditor5 in an Angular project? Is there a specific configuration I am missing or a different approach I should take?

I updated the ckeditor5 package to latest version so the issue has been fixed.
